# Comparing numeric Value stored in object >= to another object

Tags: c#, object, compare, type-conversion

In my program, i'm reading SchemData from a table.
I need to determine the column size and decide at runtime if a given value
matches the column size and could be written to that column.
In case of alpha-numeric Types like char, nvarchar,... this is no problem.

But in case of numeric values i cannot compare the value with the column size, because column size will give me the amount of bytes to store inside that column, if my understanding here is correct.

So i want to check, if my numeric values are inside the MaxValue range of that particular data type stored inside a System.Type variable of that column.

I started with determining the MaxValue using reflection and also recognizing nullable types like that:

```
public static Object GetMaxValue(this Type type)
{
    var t = GetNullableType(type);
    var f = t.GetField("MaxValue");
    if (f == null)
        return null;
    else
        return f.GetValue(null);
}

public static Type GetNullableType(Type type)
{
    Type retType = type;
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        var nullableConverter = new System.ComponentModel.NullableConverter(type);
        retType = nullableConverter.UnderlyingType;
    }
    return retType;
}
```

Now i get an object, storing the MaxValue information.

How can i compare the MaxValue stored inside an object with another value, stored inside another object (or maybe a string).
The value inside the second object (or string, as mentioned before) are read from a xml file, therefor this is not a specific type like int. It needs to be from type object.

The only thing to solve the comparison thing i thought of was implementing a method and checking for every single numeric type inside a switch and performing a try parse and return true/false.

First example method looks like this:

```
    public static bool TestMaxValue(this Type type, object compare)
    {
        var t = GetNullableType(type);
        var mv = t.GetMaxValue();
        bool ret = false;
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(t))
        {
            case TypeCode.Byte:
                {
                    Byte b;
                    if (Byte.TryParse(compare.ToString(), out b))
                        ret =(Convert.ToByte(mv) >= b);

                    break;
                }
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                {
                    Decimal b;
                    if (Decimal.TryParse(compare.ToString(), out b))
                        ret = (Convert.ToDecimal(mv) >= b);

                    break;
                }
            case TypeCode.Double:
                {
                    Double b;
                    if (Double.TryParse(compare.ToString(), out b))
                        ret = (Convert.ToDouble(mv) >= b);

                    break;
                }
            case TypeCode.Int16:
                {
                    Int16 b;
                    if (Int16.TryParse(compare.ToString(), out b))
                        ret = (Convert.ToInt16(mv) >= b);

                    break;
                }
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                {
                    Int32 b;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(compare.ToString(), out b))
                        ret = (Convert.ToInt32(mv) >= b);

                    break;
                }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Does anyone have a better idea than implementing such a method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure about the kind of storage you are relying on (and the kind of widths you are intending to measure) but, in most of the cases (all what I know), the max./min. values are defined as function of the given type. That is, if the type is a string, by its length (from length 1 to length 100), if it is an integer by integers (1 to 1000), etc. If, for example, you want to store a numeric value into a string column, you would be forced to convert it into string and thus the string rules (for length) will be applied anyway. Did I miss something?

Comment: I want to store a numeric value inside a numeric column. The data from xml File i read is unknown to me. I will get a path to a xml file and read it. The data i get there needs to be stored inside a table and every single value needs first to be checked, if it could be stored inside the matching column. Therefore i need to determine the data type of that column (i get it from GetSchemaTable()) and test the MaxValue of this Type against the incoming value from xml file. I hope i could describe as precise as possible, otherwise just ask again :).

Comment: Intending to perform any kind of operation (storage or any other thing) without knowing the type you are dealing with is not something recommendable at all (to say it "softly"). You shouldn't do that in any case. What you can do always is relying on strings (and on their lengths for size checkings). But still it does not seem to make too much sense to store something you don't know its type, this is a basic defining feature of the given bit of information. You should either store the types together with the info or "guess them"; knowing numeric types, for example, is straightforward.

Comment: well, i didn't want to discuss about how much sense it would make to do something or to not do it. I have a specification, which says, read a xml file where the element tags are the names of a column. Check that column if the value stored in an attribut of that tag will fit in this column. If it does not fit, continue with the next one. And so on. This shall be some kind of import from different systems, where the xml file will every time be of that format, but maybe the values will not match the defined import table. and that needs to be checked.

Comment: reply on "without knowing the type you are dealing with": i know the type of that column. I get it by reading SchemTable from DataReader. I just wanted to know if there is a better way than implementing a function like TestMaxValue as shown in the question.

Comment: You are here asking for help and this is what I have provided. Some times, the help consists in offering you other options and allowing you to see thing in other way. I see the solution pretty clear (don't do that in this way); if you prefer to do it anyway, I don't know how can be help.

Comment: If you know the type of the column and you know the data which you want to write there, the solution is straightforward: the column will only allow you to write in the right type. Perform a conversion/casting to the right type, if an error is triggered then you cannot write in this column; if not just rely on the given type. Example: "this" can not be written into an integer column and thus you don't need to waste your time in determining whether an ideal size would match it or not. "123" can be written to an integer column, check whether it is within the (int) boundaries of the given column.

Comment: I see that you accepted a solution on the lines of what I proposed. In any case, bear in mind that this does not deliver what you want either: the max./min. values of a given type do not need to match the ones in the corresponding columns. It is a bit weird to me why you were complaining about my proposal and you have answered "But great solution anyways, thanks." to a code applying these ideas. Anyway... you are welcome.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your answers because of insufficient language knowledge as im no native, but i realy appreciate your help and approvals. Backto topic, i think, if i get a System.Type from SchemaTable, than i think i can trust, that it will fit also the Type of the table's column. Therefor SchemTable delivers different properties of a) the System.Type and b) the ProviderSpecificType, so i think they have to match otherwise they wouldn't get returned in same object.

Comment: I don't know the kind of storage you are using; but any database allows to set up the max./min. allowed values for each column. The maximum value for an integer in .NET is 214748367, there are quite a few integer-type columns in databases allowing much smaller values (when I define an integer-type column, I rarely allow so big values). Also bear in mind that the type definitions (and thus their max./min values) are different in different programming languages (the max. min value for an int is not the same in all the languages).

Comment: you can confirm that the given value is within the boundaries of the type in .NET but, not necessarily in the target DB language; neither in the specific column (defined as this type, but perhaps with more restricted boundaries). The code in the answer gives you an initial grasp but you cannot trust it blindly: either retrieve the boundaries from the given column in the database or set up a try catch just in case.

Comment: ok, now i got you. :) Took a while but now i understood what you wanted to tell me. I will keep that in mind, thanks. (if i could give your comment +1 i would)

Comment: You are welcome. With "thanks" (+ bringing all the ideas into account) is more than enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Convert.ChangeType and IComparable to solve this. All primitive types are inherited from IComparable.
This snippet is working at my end.
Make sure u catch the exception inside or outside as ChangeType throws format exception if the conversion type is incorrect.

```
 public static bool TestMaxValue(this Type type, object compare)
    {
        var t = GetNullableType(type);
        var mv = t.GetMaxValue();
        bool ret = false;
        try
        {
            IComparable maxValue = Convert.ChangeType(mv, t) as IComparable;
            IComparable currentValue = Convert.ChangeType(compare, t) as IComparable;
            if (maxValue != null && currentValue != null)
                ret = maxValue.CompareTo(currentValue) > 0;
        }
        catch (FormatException exception)
        {
            //handle is here
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Although its recommended to not write extension methods as it reduces type safety. Create extension methods for specific types separately like

```
 public static bool TestMaxValue(this int? value, int compareValue)
        {
            var intValue = value.GetValueOrDefault();
            var ret = intValue.CompareTo(compareValue) > 0;
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: i think it needs to be greater or equal zero. ret = maxValue.CompareTo(currentValue) >= 0; Because MaxValue tells you the last possible value. But great solution anyways, thanks.